# How to call a javascript function whose parameters are from a Ruby model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what I've got so far: A user will go to a view and click a button "create an event" which saves in my Event table an event with a starts_at and ends_at date.

When a user clicks create an event, the event is created in the events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :logged_in?


  def new
    @event = Event.new
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

  end


  def create

    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

    @event = @calendar.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      redirect_to '/main'
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
    end
  end

  private
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:calendar_id, :name, :starts_at, :ends_at) 
  end
```

and the users are sent automatically to their homepage (/main). This is where the html calendar will be. 
The javascript function will be in my application.js file and the calendar html will be in my main.html.erb file.

What I want to do is be able to, at the point of event creation, call a javascript function that will change the html calendar on the user's homepage to display the event (just blocking out in red the day and time). The javascript function will need to take in the **newly created event's parameters** (starts_at, ends_at) in order to work (i think).

I am very new to ruby on rails, javascript and html so please if you have a helpful answer explain as if I was 5!!

EDIT: here is the view code I'm using to link to the event controller's create method:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>Create A Meeting</h1>

      <%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>

          <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Title" %>
          <!--< f.collection_select :location, Location.all, :id, :locName %> FOR WHEN LOCATIONS ARE A THING-->
          <!--< f.text_field :body, :placeholder => "Short Description" %> NEXT STEP -->

          <div>
            <h2>when do you want it to start?</h2>
            <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, :placeholder => "when do you want it?"   %>
          </div>



          <div>
            <h2>when do you want it to end?</h2>
            <%= f.datetime_select :ends_at, :placeholder => "when should it end?"  %>
          </div>


          <%= f.submit "Create Meeting", class: "btn-submit" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the Pages controller (where main is generated):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  #before_action :require_customer, only: [:main]

  def home

  end


  def main

  end

end
```

the routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'
  get '/main' => 'pages#main'
  get '/signup' => 'customers#new'
  resources :customers, :calendars

  get '/signupbus' => 'businesses#new'
  resources :businesses

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  get '/compose' => 'events#new'
  resources :events
```

here a snippet of the html for my weekly calendar view (it is awful I know, but I don't know how to make it better):

```
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="main2">

      <a class="btn-main" href="/compose">Create a Meeting</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class = "calendarContainer">

<table class= "weeklyCalendar">
  <tr>
    <td class = "blankTopLeft">
    </td>
    <td class = "daytd" width=75 valign=top >
      <p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Mon</span></i></p>
      <p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>14</span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class = "daytd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal ><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Tue</span></i></p>
      <p class=MsoNormal ><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>15</span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class = "daytd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Wed</span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class = "daytd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Thu</span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class = "daytd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Fri</span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class = "daytd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Sat</span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td class= "daytd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>Sun</span></i></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "Monday" style='height:28.05pt'>
    <td class = "timetd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
              text-align:right;line-height:normal'><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;
              font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>  9:00  </span></i></p>
    </td>
    <td id = "mon900" class ="freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td id = "tue900" class ="freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td id = "wed900" class = "freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td id = "thu900" class = "freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td id = "fri900" class = "freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td id = "sat900" class = "freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    <td id = "sun900" class = "freeslot" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
              normal'>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style='height:27.75pt'>
    <td class = "timetd" width=75 valign=top>
      <p class=MsoNormal align=right style='margin-bottom:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;
              text-align:right;line-height:normal'><i><span style='font-size:13.0pt;
              font-family:"Calibri Light",sans-serif'>10:00</span></i></p>
    </td>
```

Comment: You mean to say as soon as you create the event that should be visible into the calendar at main html page. Please confirm for the same.

Comment: @Bharatsoni yes that is what I mean

Comment: I am not sure why you need javascript for this at all? If you stored new event in the database and then redirect to main page, the main page will be rebuild, including newly created event? Did I miss something?

Comment: @BroiSatse All my main page contains at the moment is a drawn html calendar, there is no connection between the html and the events model or the calendar model. This is what I'm trying to establish, so that when an event is created, the html is changed accordingly

Comment: Okay, I see what is happening now. You don't need JS. and you don't need the `format.js`. all you need to do here is to reload the event from your `main` method in your `PagesContrller`.

Comment: @SunnyK I don't know what you mean, could you possibly show me in an answer? I have not yet integrated events into my calendar, as I do not know how.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the new event with your existing `create` method from your Controller, and you redirected to the `PagesController`'s `main` method, then, you will have to reload the `event` in this your `main` method.

To do this, you will need to know the `id` of the needed `event` which means that you will have to pass it from wherever you are redirecting, which means you will have to make space for it in your route for the `main` method.

So, in your route:

```
get '/main/:callendar_id' => 'page#main'
```

And then from your `create` method, you redirect to this path with the id of the newly created event.

```
 def create

    @calendar = current_customer.calendar

    @event = @calendar.events.build(event_params)
    if @event.save
      redirect_to "/main/#{@callendar.id}"
    else
      redirect_to '/compose'
    end
  end
```

and reload the event from the `main` method of your `PagesController`:

```
def main
  @callendar = Callendar.find(params[:callendar_id])
end
```

This will work well for you, and give you the updated callendar with the new event on your `main` page.

Comment: I am not very familiar with AJAX, in fact I have never used it before. How would I use JS to call the create method/save the new event? Will the event still appear in my database?

Comment: yes. all you just have to do is to add `remote: true` attribute to the link you are currently using to create an event. I mean the link the user clicks to create an event. If you drop your code for this link, I can show you how, and help update the above create action as well.

Comment: ok thanks very much, I have added the code to the end of my question

Comment: so now in the create.js.erb file, I can put any javascript I like? So because I want to change the appearance of the html, I can do all those jquery calls from within that file?

Comment: also, after adding in the code you gave me, now when I click the button "create meeting" I am not sent back to the main page, which I was previously, why is this?

Comment: If you want it to redirect, you will have to specify that in the `format.js`

Though, if you are redirecting to another resource, then you might loose the  `@event` object.

Comment: the initial intention was that after a user clicks 'create a meeting' they will be redirected to the homepage (main) where they will see the updated calendar. Is your solution still valid?

Comment: No. I will delete and then rewrite. kindly update your question with the `HomeController` and `route.rb` then, I will delete this answer and provide the right one.

Comment: I have updated the answer. This should work well for you now. :)

Comment: I do not understand why this would work, if my html is not being changed, how will it be changed in the main.html? My calendar snippet of HTML has been made in main.html.  Surely I will still need to use JS/JQuery to update the calendar visually?